# Slope of ROC increases

Tags: roc

[image]Hi, my ROC curve seems weird because in most of the cases, the slope of ROC curve should decrease.

Can anyone help to interpret this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answered question may also address your observation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66837/why-does-my-roc-curve-look-like-this-is-it-correct

Answer (score 5):

"Real" ROC curves should always be convex by construction. However, in empirical data, concavity can occur through noise. [Pesce et al. (2010, *Academic Radiology*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.acra.2010.04.001) discuss the phenomenon and investigate the implications of concave ROC curves on medical decisions. You may also be interested in [this presentation by Gneiting et al. (2019)](https://www.ecmwf.int/sites/default/files/elibrary/2019/18947-receiver-operating-characteristic-roc-curves.pdf).